# How can i Shading positive and positive areas beyond ZERO line: anomaly in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: i want to plot the INDIAN OCEAN DIPOLE INDEX like this in python from 1979-2014]

YEARS=np.arange(np.datetime64("1979-07-01"), np.datetime64("2015-07-01"), dtype='datetime64[Y]')

DATA=(-0.5635147,
0.04471147,
1.4331872,
-0.09839201,
0.24226117,
-0.08254513,
0.29853868,
-0.79512143,
-0.79967123,
-0.1649437,
-0.21625134,
-0.22912416,
-1.0080668,
-0.46486163,
0.62073106,
-1.0641583,
-0.27737525,
0.35150194,
-0.4560886,
0.1954728,
0.5420398,
0.3017679,
-0.055624068,
-0.38038778,
0.5891459,
0.7454071,
0.2169415,
-0.09263754,
0.455848,
0.35939074,
0.38828057,
-0.933143,
1.1125178,
0.026810408,
-0.2547031,
0.012055755)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's unclear. Correct the title that can't be understood and add a description or an explanation on the body. Also see [ask].